# What is this notification icon that looks like the casting/screenshare icon?

Tags: notification-icons, android-12

[image]

It looks like the casting/screenshare icon, but I've checked and screen sharing is turned off?  I've ended all running processes just to be safe, but it still persists.  Nothing else shows when pulling the notification bar down.

EDIT: I have the OnePlus 8T+ 5G (KB2007) Stock, Stock ROM, but unlocked and on Verizon's network (still TMO stock firmware).